# For loop not woking? Roblox studio

Tags: for-loop, debugging, lua, roblox

Code:

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local InvDataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("InvDataStore")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local Id = player.UserId
    
    local Inventory = Instance.new("Folder")
    Inventory.Name = "Inventory"
    Inventory.Parent = player
    
    local Inv = InvDataStore:GetAsync(Id)
    print(Inv)
    print(table.concat(Inv, " "))
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local Id = player.UserId
    local InvTable = {}
    
    for i, v in pairs(game.Players:FindFirstChild(player.Name).Inventory:GetChildren()) do
        print("Repear")
        if v:IsA("NumberValue") then
            table.insert(InvTable, v)
            print(v)
        end

    end
    
    print(InvTable)
    print(table.concat(InvTable, " "))
    InvDataStore:SetAsync(Id, InvTable)
end)
```

Output:

13:25:35.288 - Untitled Game auto-recovery file was created
Realism Mod is currently running v2.09! (x2)
table: 0x08cb53598b2d3aa1

table: 0xd8ce847b521d4091
1
13:26:26.703 - Disconnect from ::ffff:127.0.0.1|60556

Explorer:

It seems to be skipping this loop:

```
for i, v in pairs(game.Players:FindFirstChild(player.Name).Inventory:GetChildren()) do
        print("Repear")
        if v:IsA("NumberValue") then
            table.insert(InvTable, v)
            print(v)
        end

    end
```

as it seems to not print repear (repeat) OR v (Value) anyone know whats up?

Note: The thing i dont understand, is it doesnt print the value after the save, and before the save, and forgetting the for loop. I can provide extra things to.

Comment: Unrelated, but what if you replace `game.Players:FindFirstChild(player.Name)` with `player`?

Comment: Changes nothing ilmao, i did that earlier, but thnx for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

It is ignoring the loop because when it gets to `game.Players:FindFirstChild(player.Name)` the return will be nil, due to that player just leaved the server. What you can try to do is iterating directly from the player object you have, you don't need to look for the object player if you already have it.
Try:

```
for i, v in pairs(player.Inventory:GetChildren()) do
    print("Repear")
    if v:IsA("NumberValue") then
        table.insert(InvTable, v)
        print(v)
    end
end
```

also it is a good practice to store data during the game and not when it leaves, all those objects are removed too when the player leaves, it is better to handle the table during the game and during player removing just update the data store.
Also a good practice is to update datastore for the player every ~5 minutes